# How to perform 'AND' operation in two lists in c# LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a table '**Property**' which is having **location** , **Property_Type**  and many other fields also.

My input is having a list of locations and each location has got another list of filtering conditions. For eg:- My locations are - [A, B & C]. For each of these locations there is another list namely - [Apartment, Land, House etc].

Sample input data:

A - [Apartment, Land, House] ---> means - Location A with 3 filtering options

B - [Land, House]

C - [Apartment, Land]

I need to find all the properties in location A with property_type [Apartment, Land, House] and in location B with property_type [Land, House] etc

I made dictionary object like this;

```
Dictionary<string,List<PropertyType>> PTypeDictionary =new Dictionary<string,List<PropertyType>>();
```

**Note**: PropertyType is enum

Now my input data is in this dictionary - Keys are the locations and Values are the list of Property_Types.

How to write LINQ query to find all the properties in these locations along with the filtering property_type?

Comment: LINQ to what? LINQ to object or LINQ to entity or LINQ to SQL?

Comment: LINQ to entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your custom expression, or simply union all of them into single result.

Code sample below is example how to do the task with `Union`. Tested in LINQPad, and it should work in Entity Framework too.

```
var PTypeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, IList<PropertyType>>
{
    ["A"] = new List<PropertyType> { PropertyType.Apartment, PropertyType.Land, PropertyType.House},
    ["B"] = new List<PropertyType> { PropertyType.Land, PropertyType.House},
    ["C"] = new List<PropertyType> { PropertyType.Apartment, PropertyType.Land}
};

var empty = Properties.Where(x => 1==2);
var props = PTypeDictionary.Aggregate(empty, (a, f) => a.Union(Properties.Where(p => p.Location == f.Key && f.Value.Contains(p.Type))));        
var pList = props.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But why are you using 'empty' and what are these a & f here ?

Comment: You can learn more about `Aggregate` method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx). Aggregate method apply the accumulator function over a sequence, in this case your filter dictionary. `empty` is just empty queryable to start with, and then for every item in your dictionary, it will `Union` the current value to the previous value.